# How to encourage flavour development in raspberries

Tags: fruits, variety-selection, raspberries, rain

We planted raspberry plants in our garden a few years back. We quickly learned that to get most fruit production they need to be cut back to just a few inches above ground once they start to die back in the winter since only new growth develops fruit each year.

This year the plants look healthy and have grown to 5-6ft as normal, the fruits are huge too. However amongst the red, early fruit bearing varieties the fruit is very watery and flavourless, even when very ripe. (The yellow variety has more usual sized fruit and more flavour). I suspect this might be because of the large amount of rain we had earlier in the year.

Is there anything practical we can do further to encourage the development of flavour in the larger red variety? Or is this just a natural consequence of the maturity of the plants and we should plan to replace the older ones?

Comment: My own experience with raspberries is - assuming that the variety you have has tasted good in the past - that, yes, too much rain as the fruits are ripening can negatively affect their flavor. There's no need to replace the plants, as they'll bear normally and more flavorfully if the weather dries out.

Comment: Don't let the fruit get over ripe before you harvest it. The more sugar it contains, the less "raspberry flavor" it has. If you end up with *too much* "flavor", you can always add some sugar from a supermarket!